# What does "to conjure with" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> "What was so demoralizing to me was to envision my two aunts, who had
> long been figures of power and authority ***to conjure with***,
> reduced in the last stage of their life to such servility, fear, and
> silence."

I know that there exists a phrase "a name to conjure with" which, according to the Oxford Dictionary, means "the name of an important person within a particular sphere of activity." Is "to conjure with" in this sentence a variation of that phrase? If so, what does it mean?

Comment: It's a dated "fixed form" usage. Compare *[He was a] [**figure to reckon with**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+figure+to+reckon+with%22) on the village council*. Which is still "dated" - but not *quite* so much - with the verb more "accurately" cast into the passive, as [*a man **to be** reckoned with*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=man+to+be+reckoned+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cman%20to%20be%20reckoned%20with%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right lines with the definition you found, it is just of a more specific idiom.

"A name to conjure with" means that the person or thing named is important, well-known, or well-respected.

The author of your text has played with the idiom a little and said that they were "*figures of power and authority* to conjure with", which I would take to mean that they were important or well-known as figures of power or authority.

Comment: The old meaning was to use the name of a powerful being (usually a deity) in an utterance or magic spell e.g. to conjure the Devil to depart, one might say 'In the name of God, I conjure you to depart'. Now just means to make an impression, e.g. I knew HG Wells when he was a boy, my cousin is the Prime Minister, etc.